# Unable to declare -f via ssh successfully

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I'm trying to declare a functions over a remote server via SSH.

```
funcA () { echo 'do something'; }
ssh $somewhere " $(declare -f funcA); funcA "
```

and I am keep getting:

```
Badly placed ()'s.
{: Command not found.
```

Why's that?

Comment: have you tried: `ssh $somewhere " bash -c '$(declare -f funcA); funcA' "`?

Comment: Cannot reproduce with the code shown.

Comment: Strike that; I can reproduce the problem with `csh -c " $(declare -f funcA); funcA "`. Your remote shell appears to be some variant of `csh`, in which case you can't use a `bash` function definition.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the remote user has their login shell set to `csh` and you're giving it `bash` code. This is like trying to compile Java code with a C compiler, or pasting Python code into PHP.

You can instead ask `csh` to run `bash`, and then feed in your commands to bash:

```
ssh $somewhere "bash -s" <<< " $(declare -f funcA); funcA "
```

Comment: I'd go with `-c`; if `funcA` tries to read from standard input, you get a race condition with the script itself.

Comment: @chepner How would you handle escaping? There's no race condition since the function is not invoked until the last line of the input, but having stdin available would be nice.

Comment: Something like `ssh host "bash -c \"$(declare -f funcA); funcA\""`, although I'm not positive that works. I don't recall if the the output of `declare -f` is guaranteed to be useable as shell input.

Comment: There's no escaping in that example and so it fails for `funcA() { echo "hello world"; }`

Comment: Oh, right, since `declare -f` outputs newlines, not semicolons. This is why I'm a fan of Plan C: copy a script to the remote host and execute that.

Comment: It's because `bash -c "echo "hello world""` is not a valid command when it arrives on the remote side

Comment: Not quite; the function definition gets sent to the remote, but it goes over as `funcA () \n { \n echo "Hello World" \n }`, and since it isn't quoted, the newlines are removed as arbitrary whitespace, leaving the final `}` to be interpreted as an argument to `echo`. The function definition never gets closed, leading to `funcA: -c: line 3: syntax error: unexpected end of file`.

Comment: Note that `ssh ssh "bash -c \"$(echo 'funcA () { echo "hi"; }'); funcA\""` would work, since nothing in the command substitution is sensitive to whitespace being collapsed.

Comment: It *is* quoted and linefeeds are sent literally. Csh apparently doesn't allow linefeeds in literals anyways, so they would also need escaping, but they're not removed. Your command happens to work but replacing `"hi"` with `"hi there"` would fail

Comment: Like I said: Plan C :)